# What is the proper way to create a link for mobile devices?

Tags: android, jquery, css, mobile

So I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I purchased a mobile theme from one of my favorite places. Theme works great except for one area. There is an icon on the top right that allows a user to tap it and it shows some social media sharing icons, where a user should then be able to tap the icon of their choice and share on the proper social site.

In any browser, the links seem to work fine, but when I use my Droid or my tablet, although the show/hide social icons works just fine, the ability to actually tap the icon and share the link does not however.

Here is the code for the section:

```
<div class="shareDialog shareDialogMenu">
<div class="shareDialogArrow"></div>
<div class="shareDialogContent">
     <ul class="shareDialogIconList">
        <li><a href="mailto:?subject=Subject&body=Content"><div class="shareDialogMail"></div>Mail Link</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(curPageURL()); ?>" target="_blank"><div class="shareDialogFb"></div>Share Link</a></li>

        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=<?php echo urlencode($row['headline']); ?>&url=<?php echo urlencode(curPageURL()); ?>" target="_blank"><div class="shareDialogTwitter"></div>Tweet Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The links do in fact share properly on the social networks, in any browser, but not on mobile devices, and the linking structure appears to be a standard a href tag. But I am baffled as to why the actual clicks will not work on a mobile device. Any thoughts or a fresh set of eyes is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you test in just Chrome or another browser too??

Comment: I've test this in Chrome and in Firefox on a desktop, and tested it on a droid phone and droid tablet. On the desktop browser, the links work, on the phone/tablet, they do not.

Comment: I'm reffering to the mobile version browsers...

Comment: I can't install Chrome on my Droid, guess the OS is outdated or something. The browser on my device is AppleWebkit/533.1 Version/4.0 Mobile Safari

Comment: Can you install Opera Mobile or something like: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/android/ for testing

Comment: I did manage to get FireFox installed for the droid - Im going to test it now and see what happens.

Comment: So it does seem to work on FireFox Mobile Version. But for the Safari browser (at least what I have installed) it doesn't. Is there anything wrong with my standard html structure that would prevent the link from working properly on browsers?

Comment: Maybe the way Safari interprete Javascript differs...check this out: http://quirksmode.org/m/table.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the problem could be with the `div` element within your `a` elements.

`div`s are block level elements, which cannot reside within inline elements like `a`s. Although you could use CSS to style the divs in question as `display: inline;`

Some browsers allow the invalid use of block and inline elements, and some will simply close the `a` element once the `div` starts, meaning your text won't actually be a link.

Another solution would be to use a `span` instead of a `div`.

Hope this makes sense, and helps you fix your issue.